# Background search for changes in TFS source control

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, tfs, sourcegear-vault

[SourceGear Vault](https://www.sourcegear.com/vault/)'s client app has the ability to background search for changes. This is very useful because at any time I can take a quick peek and see what changes my team members have checked in and that I need to get latest on. This is also helpful for previewing any merges that might be necessary. And on a day to day basis, it helps me get a sense of what parts of the codebase are seeing the most churn.

[image: SourceGear Vault Client]

Is there a way to get this same functionality with Team Foundation Server, either with native features or a plugin? I know there is a Compare feature, but it takes way too long to be useful. Unless it could periodically refresh itself like Vault does, but I haven't found a way to do that. Anything new with Visual Studio 2010?

Answer (score 0):

While this doesn't directly answer your question, I set up alerts on TFS so that I get sent an email anytime someone checks something in.  This lets me see the churn that's happening and lets me see if someone is playing in a place that they shouldn't be.

Comment: i've done this as well, but it doesn't seem to help me as much. I think getting individual emails vs seeing it in one place (with quick access to other source control operations like compare/get latest) turns it into an information overload thing that I end up not wanting to check my alerts folder

Comment: You might be able to home-roll this if no one finds a solution:  http://blogs.msdn.com/chrisid/archive/2010/02/15/introducing-the-tfs-background-job-agent-and-service.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to write a bit of C# code to do whatever you want and attach it to TFS as an event handler.

A search (e.g. "TFS event handler") will get quite a few hits
e.g. [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfspowertools/thread/27d25b81-d91c-4ce2-9ee6-c6f5a8406de6) on MSDN and this [event handler dll](http://www.codeplex.com/TFSEventHandler) on CodePlex